# Compare two csv files containing floating-point data and print their difference statistics

Tags: shell-script, awk, csv

I have two csv files: a.csv and b.csv. Both these files contain same set of rows. For example:

a.csv:

```
Yield
5.68
1.34
1.47
9.01
7.59
```

b.csv:

```
Yield
5.68
2.01
0.78
7.98
8.17
```

I need to compare these two files (the files are always have the same order i.e. ith row in a.csv always corresponds to ith row in b.csv) and print the following statistics:

```
a.csv is greater than b.csv in 2/5 cases.
a.csv is smaller than b.csv in 2/5 cases.
a.csv is equal to b.csv in 1/5 cases.
```

Ref: I have written an R-code to do it, but want to get this thing done in Unix itself, maybe using awk?

```
a <- read.csv('path/a.csv')
b <- read.csv('path/b.csv')
sum(a > b)
sum(a < b)
sum(a == b)
```

Comment: If you have `R`, why not use `Rscript` to run it as a script? Also, can we assume the files are always sorted in the same way? Do we always compare line X from file1 to line X from file 2?

Comment: So it is wrong to say that 
a.csv is greater than b.csv in 3/5 cases.
a.csv is smaller than b.csv in 1/5 cases.
a.csv is equal to b.csv in 1/5 cases.
:)

Comment: I don't want to call R script inside this Unix script, as I am not sure whether the client machine will have the R-base installed.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ paste a.csv b.csv | awk -F '\t' 'NR > 1 { ++cmp[$1>$2 ? 1 : $1==$2 ? 0 : -1] } END { printf "greater\t= %d\nsmaller\t= %d\nequal\t= %d\n", cmp[1],cmp[-1],cmp[0] }'
greater = 2
smaller = 2
equal   = 1
```

This creates a two-column input for a short `awk` program using `paste`.  The contents of `a.csv` will be in the first field and the contents of `b.csv` will be in the second field, and there will be a tab character in-between these.

The header line is discarded, and the first block of code increments one of three counters in the array `cmp`.  The value of `cmp[1]` is incremented if the first field (`a.csv`) is greater than the second field (`b.csv`). The value of `cmp[0]` is incremented if the two fields are equal.  The value of `cmp[-1]` is incremented if the second field is larger than the first.

At the end, in the `END` block, the results are printed.

The same thing in Perl, using its spaceship operator `<=>`:

```
$ paste a.csv b.csv | perl -a -F'\t' -e '$. > 1 && ++$cmp{$F[0] <=> $F[1]}; END { printf "greater\t= %d\nsmaller\t= %d\nequal\t= %d\n", $cmp{1},$cmp{-1},$cmp{0} }'
greater = 2
smaller = 2
equal   = 1
```

`$.` in Perl is the same as `NR` in `awk`, more or less, so `$. > 1` skips the header line in the input.  If you used `-MEnglish`, you could change `$.` into `$NR`.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR==1 { next }
NR==FNR {
    v[FNR] = $1
    next
}
{
    if      ( v[FNR] > $1 ) { gt++ }
    else if ( v[FNR] < $1 ) { lt++ }
    else                    { eq++ }
}
END {
    tot = gt + lt + eq
    printf "%s is greater than %s in %d/%d cases.\n", ARGV[1], ARGV[2], gt, tot
    printf "%s is smaller than %s in %d/%d cases.\n", ARGV[1], ARGV[2], lt, tot
    printf "%s is equal to %s in %d/%d cases.\n",     ARGV[1], ARGV[2], eq, tot
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk a.csv b.csv
a.csv is greater than b.csv in 2/5 cases.
a.csv is smaller than b.csv in 2/5 cases.
a.csv is equal to b.csv in 1/5 cases.
```